# Error in running commands with manage.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.4

I just started learning django by using tango with django.

I did everything up till creating django project.
The problem I have is running with "manage.py" file.

When I ever I type

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

it says

```
python: can't open file'manage.py'
```

So I tried

```
$ python c:\Users\<username>\tango_with_django_project\manage.py runserver
```

then it worked.  Is there any way that I can run manage.py without typing long line like second one?

thanks

Comment: Work around would be to add `c:\Users\<username>\tango_with_django_project`  to the `PATH` variable

Comment: It seems like you are using windows os. So you don't have to use the `$` symbol, it should be `c:\Users\<username>\tango_with_django_project\> python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Adding "c:\Users\<username>\tango_with_django_project" to the PATH variable does not change anything... and my mistake for writing $

Comment: you could navigate to the location of that file and run it directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to type each time, when you to run django dev server, just create .bat file (if you use Windows, as I can see) with this (working) string.
After that you need only double-click on this file to run server.

Comment: how do you create a .bat file?

Comment: First of all, check if you can see file extensions. I mean, if you see text file, you must see MyTextFile.txt. After that just create a .txt file on your desktop, put `python c:\Users\<username>\tango_with_django_project\manage.py runserver` inside and save it. After that rename file and change ext from .txt to .bat and click Yes. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed current dir to the django project?

```
c:
cd \Users\<username>\tango_with_django_project\
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I'm very new to progrmmaing so i have no idea how to change my current dir to django project. I typed as same as you wrote above in command prompot but it just says " the system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: `cd` is the command to **c**hange **d**irectory. Did you replaced the `<username>` with your account name?  You should type the same path as you used to point to `manage.py` command.